# Java How to use for loop to populate Year and Month list?

Tags: java, for-loop, calendar

How can I loop year and months to display below output?
Limit of the period to show is current month and year
Also, show 3 years inclusive of the year as of date. Meaning if its 2019 now, show 2018 and 2017.

I tried with some code to run as java application in hope to get the expected output below but this is what I've tried and got.

Would appreciate much if anyone can shed some light here.

```
public class TestClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    //month=5, index starts from 0
    int month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    //year=2019
    int year = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {    //year
        for(int j= 0; j <= month; j++) {    //month
        System.out.println("Value of year: " + (year - 2)); //start from 2017 and iterate to 2 years ahead
        System.out.println("Value of month: " + (month + 1)); //start from January (index val: 1) and iterate to today's month
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Expected Output:**

2017
1
2017
2
2017
3
2017
4
2017
5
2017
6
2017
7
2017
8
2017
9
2017
10
2017
11
2017
12

2018
1
2018
2
2018
3
2018
4
2018
5
2018
6
2018
7
2018
8
2018
9
2018
10
2018
11
2018
12

2019
1
2019
2
2019
3
2019
4
2019
5
2019
6

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `YearMonth` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). If on Java 6 or 7, use it through the [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code. I'm using java 8 and java.time.LocalDate,

```
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
int year = currentDate.getYear();
int month = currentDate.getMonthValue();

for (int i = year - 2; i <= year; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 12; j++) {
        if (i == year && j == month) {
            System.out.print(i + " " + j + " ");
            break;
        }
            System.out.print(i + " " + j + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
2017 1 2017 2 2017 3 2017 4 2017 5 2017 6 2017 7 2017 8 2017 9 2017 10 2017 11 2017 12 2018 1 2018 2 2018 3 2018 4 2018 5 2018 6 2018 7 2018 8 2018 9 2018 10 2018 11 2018 12 2019 1 2019 2 2019 3 2019 4 2019 5 2019 6
```

Comment: Tried this and it worked but for mine, it stopped at 2019 5 instead of 2019 6 . So I added 1 to j and it worked fab for me . 

System.out.println(i + " " + (j + 1) + " " );

Comment: Are your sure you have implemented for loops correctly ? i'm pretty sure it will print 2019 06.please double check for loop conditions.

Comment: So I was still using java.util.calendar in my code just now while also modified my loop conditions to be the same as what you suggested. Changed it to use java.time.LocalDate and yes it printed 2019.06. Realised now that when using localtime, the index value starts from 1 while in java.util.calendar, the index value begins from 0

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
YearMonth                        // Represent a specific month as a whole.
.now(                            // Determine the current month as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" )    // Specify your desired/expected time zone.
)                                // Returns a `YearMonth` object.
.withMonth( 1 )                  // Move back to January of this year. Returns another `YearMonth` object rather than changing (mutating) the original, per the immutable objects pattern.
.minusYears( 2 )                 // Jump back two years in the past. Returns yet another `YearMonth` object.
```

## *java.time*

You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

Also, you are ignoring the issue of time zone. A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

### `YearMonth`

You care only about the year and the month, without any date. So use the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
YearMonth yearMonthNow = YearMonth.now( z ) ;

YearMonth yearMonthJanuaryTwoYearAgo = yearMonthNow.withMonth( 1 ).minusYears( 2 ) ;
```

Increment a month at a time, collecting as we go.

```
ArrayList< YearMonth > yearMonths = new ArrayList<>();
YearMonth ym = yearMonthJanuaryTwoYearAgo ;
while( ! ym.isAfter( yearMonthNow ) ) 
{
    yearMonths.add( ym ) ;
    // Set up the next loop.
    ym = ym.plusMonths( 1 ) ;
}
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( yearMonths ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/FgclMj).

> [2017-01, 2017-02, 2017-03, 2017-04, 2017-05, 2017-06, 2017-07, 2017-08, 2017-09, 2017-10, 2017-11, 2017-12, 2018-01, 2018-02, 2018-03, 2018-04, 2018-05, 2018-06, 2018-07, 2018-08, 2018-09, 2018-10, 2018-11, 2018-12, 2019-01, 2019-02, 2019-03, 2019-04, 2019-05, 2019-06]

If you want to exclude the current month, use:

```
while( ym.isBefore( yearMonthNow ) )
```

Comment: im maintaining it at old versions as some users of this application is still using old java at their place. regardless, this was great info to me, im amused at how it can be done w the newer java . thanks so much, mate

Comment: @vlina Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. The legacy date-time classes are *really* terrible; avoid them.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: using the year and month in the loop

```
for(int i = year-2; i <= year; i++) {    //year

    for(int j= 1; (j <= 12 || (j == month && i == year)); j++) {    //month
        System.out.println("Value of year: " + i); //start from 2017 and iterate to 2 years ahead
        System.out.println("Value of month: " + j); //start from January (index val: 1) and iterate to today's month
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `int month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);` catered for?

Comment: @ScaryWombat: Apologies, I completely misread the question. I have updated the answer.